# Passar e receber o id do campo por parâmetro

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse código html:

```
<input type="radio" name="resultado" value="Y" onclick="habilitaCampo(this.value)">Aprovado 
<input type="radio" name="resultado" value="N" onclick="habilitaCampo(this.value)">Recusado<br> 
<input type="text" id="data_validade" name="data_validade" size="15" maxlength="10" disabled="disabled" onKeyPress="mascara_data(this,event);"/>
```

E a função javascript:

```
function habilitaCampo(valor){  
  if(valor == "Y"){     
    document.getElementById("data_validade").disabled = false;  
    document.getElementById("data_validade").focus();
  }
  else{     
    document.getElementById("data_validade").disabled = true;           
  }
}
```

para habilitar ou desabilitar o campo **data_validade**. Porém queria passar o id do campo como parâmetro e poder utilizar essa função em outros campos, pois estou criando várias funções iguais e desnecessárias, e não consigo passar e receber o valor corretamente. 
Podem me ajudar nessa questão?

Comment: Qual é o campo que queres passar? `data_validade`?

Comment: E porque tu não passa o valor de uma vez na função: onclick="habilitarCampo('y')"?

Comment: @Sergio esse campo mesmo!

Comment: @Aline a idéia seria essa, mas está dando erro **Uncaught ReferenceError: habilitaCampo is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (ajudantes.php:86)** sendo 86 a linha do input radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso do HTML que tens, podias simplificar e enviar o estado diretamente uma vez que cada `radio` tem o seu próprio invocador da função.

```js
function habilitaCampo(estado, id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.disabled = !estado;
  if (estado == true) el.focus();
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="resultado" onclick="habilitaCampo(true, 'data_validade')">Aprovado
<input type="radio" name="resultado" onclick="habilitaCampo(false, 'data_validade')">Recusado<br>
<input type="text" id="data_validade" name="data_validade" size="15" maxlength="10" disabled="disabled" onKeyPress="mascara_data(this, event);" />
```

Isso implica que a função `habilitaCampo` está acessível ao escopo global, ie. que tens por exemplo no ficheiro HTML dentro de uma tag `<script>` e fora de qualquer outra função.

---

Outra maneira, uma vez que dizes estar a repetir código, seria fazer sem JavaScript inline. Com `.addEventListener` de uma maneira organizada para poupar código:

```js
function ativador(nome, id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByName(nome), function(radio) {
    radio.addEventListener('click', habilitaCampo.bind(radio, el));
  });
}

function habilitaCampo(el) {
  el.disabled = this.value == 'N';
  if (!el.disabled) el.focus();
}

ativador('resultadoA', 'data_validadeA');
ativador('resultadoB', 'data_validadeB');
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="resultadoA" value="Y">Aprovado
<input type="radio" name="resultadoA" value="N">Recusado<br>
<input type="text" id="data_validadeA" name="data_validade" size="15" maxlength="10" value="10-5-1998" disabled="disabled" onKeyPress="mascara_data(this,event);" />

<hr>

<input type="radio" name="resultadoB" value="Y">Aprovado
<input type="radio" name="resultadoB" value="N">Recusado<br>
<input type="text" id="data_validadeB" name="data_validade" size="15" maxlength="10" value="10-5-1998" disabled="disabled" onKeyPress="mascara_data(this,event);" />
```

Comment: Sérgio, aqui funcionou corretamente, mas no meu código não quis funcionar. Vou continuar testando aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: @thiagofred esse erro _"habilitaCampo is not defined "_ diz-me que tens essa função dentro de outra. Um `onload = function() {}` ou `.ready(function(){}`. É esse o caso?

Comment: @thiagofred juntei outra maneira de fazer isso.

Comment: Sergio, não apenas uma outra função no campo de **data_validade** para mascarar no formato xx/xx/xxxx

Comment: @thiagofred podes mostrar como está todo o HTML de uma ponta à outra?

Comment: Refiz apenas o código com os três campo que me enviou em um novo arquivo, e continuou ocorrendo o erro, no Chrome. Ao testar no Internet Explorer o erro não aconteceu. É apenas incompatibilidade ou há outro erro não observado?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59522/discussion-between-sergio-and-thiagofred).

Answer (score 1):

Assim acredito que deva funcionar Thiago:

```js
    function habilitaCampo(valor, id){  
        if(valor == "Y"){     
          document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;  
          document.getElementById(id).focus();
        }
        else{     
          document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;           
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="resultado" value="Y" onclick="habilitaCampo(this.value, 'data_validade')">Aprovado 
    <input type="radio" name="resultado" value="N" onclick="habilitaCampo(this.value, 'data_validade')">Recusado<br> 
    <input type="text" id="data_validade" name="data_validade" size="15" maxlength="10" disabled="disabled" onKeyPress="mascara_data(this,event);"/>
```

Edited: mudei para o bloco de código para melhor visualização e teste.

Comment: Diego, no modo desenvolvedor do Chrome, dá o seguinte erro: **Uncaught ReferenceError: habilitaCampo is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (ajudantes.php:86)** , sendo a linha 86, a linha do campo input type radio.

Comment: Thiago, confira o código copiado, editei a publicação para o modo de bloco de código para melhor visualização e está correto.

Comment: Diego, realmente aqui funcionou, na minha página não funcionou, copiei o código direto e colei lá, mas não funcionou. Irei fazer outros testes. Obrigado.

Comment: ok, boa sorte. Qualquer coisa me chama. abraços